# Validating SSIS 2012 packages programatically via SSIS Catalog Managed Object Model

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'd like to validate and then execute SSIS package stored in SSIS Catalog (Project Deployment Model) via objects from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices` namespace.
When I execute [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff930482.aspx) method from [PackageInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.aspx) class it only runs validation, but no wait till its end. In [one example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/26/overview-of-the-ssis-mom.aspx) I've found author fires validation in 'fire and forget' mode - why fire it when we don't bother with result? In [another one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/11/17/ssis-and-powershell-in-sql-server-2012.aspx) execution is fired without previous validation.

1. Should I verify package before every execution?
2. If so, how to do it in synchronous mode?
3. I'm also curious with [ValidationOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.validationoperation.aspx) Status property. It's
   wrapped [`catalog.validations status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878143.aspx) column and can have, inter
   alia, values `succeeded (7)` and `completed (9)` - what is
   difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

Ad 2: I was able to wait for validation result in a loop:

```
var validationId = package.Validate(false, PackageInfo.ReferenceUsage.UseAllReferences, null);
ValidationOperation validation = package.Parent.Parent.Parent.Validations[validationId];
do
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    validation.Refresh();
}
while (!validation.Completed);
```